# CSS Loading on click of submit button

Tags: css, submit, loading

I am building an advanced search form, and upon submit of criteria it brings back search results.

I wanted to implement a page loader for this, so on submit it then triggers the loading of the page

This tutorial works for the page itself
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Can anyone help me make this work when the submit button is clicked instead?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to show your loader when your submit button is clicked by adding at to the button directly

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(ID_OF_YOUR_LOADER).style.display='initial';">
```

or in a separate script-Tag:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById(ID_OF_YOUR_SUBIMT_BUTTON).onclick=function(){
      document.getElementById(ID_OF_YOUR_LOADER).style.display='initial';
   }
</script>
```

Your loader would look like this:

```
<div id="ID_OF_YOUR_LOADER" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
```